# How to obtain the total sumation of an list and also its product using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.x

Hey guys I am a newbie at Numpy and am trying to learn but having issues. Lets say I have a list and I want to find the total and the product. I can do so in vanilla python:

```
numbers_list = [5,4,3,2,1]
total = sum(numbers_list)

product = 1
for x in numbers:
    product = product * x
```

The total should be 15 and the product 120. But how can I do it using Numpy?

Comment: Look into `np.prod`.

Comment: `np.array(numbers_list).sum()` and `np.array(numbers_list).prod()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the Python list into a Numpy array using [**numpy.asarray**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) and then use [**numpy.sum**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [**numpy.prod**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) for calculating the total sum and product respectively, observe:

```
import numpy as np

numbers_list = [5,4,3,2,1]

numbers_np_array = np.asarray(numbers_list)

total = numbers_np_array.sum()
product = numbers_np_array.prod()

print("The total is: %d" % total)
print("The product is: %d" % product)
```

**Output:**

```
The total is: 15
The product is: 120
```